# Socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused Python

Tags: python, sockets, http, httpclient

I want to write a HTTP client to test the web server. The client will use TCP connection.

```
#Import socket module
from socket import *
import sys
server_host = sys.argv[1]
server_port = int(sys.argv[2])
filename = sys.argv[3]

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((server_host,server_port))

while True:
    print 'Ready to server...'
    connectionSocket, addr = clientSocket.accept()
    print 'connected from', addr
    try:
        f = open(filename[1:])
        outputdata = f.read()
        #Send one HTTP header line into socket
        connectionSocket.sendall('\nHTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n')
        #Send the content of the requested file to the client
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):  
            connectionSocket.sendall(outputdata[i])
        #Closes the socket for this client
        connectionSocket.close()
        print 'File Received'
    except IOError:
        print 'IOError'
        #Send response message for file not found
        connectionSocket.sendall('\n404 Not Found\n') 
        #Close client socket 
        connectionSocket.close()
clientSocket.close()
```

Command lind input is:

```
python  ./client.py  127.0.0.1  8000  HelloWorld.html
```

This script outputs :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "./client.py", line 9, in <module>
clientSocket.connect((server_host,server_port))
File"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

I'm running Python 2.7.11 on Mac OS X.

I have tried searching around a lot haven't got a solution.

Comment: Is there a web server that listens to port 8000?

Comment: @Selcuk It should be.

Comment: Are you not sure? Can you connect to `http://127.0.0.1:8000` using a web browser?

Comment: @Selcuk pretty sure. I've tried a lot.

Comment: @Selcuk I could use the web browser to connect to the server. The port listens to port 8000.  

serverSocket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8000))

Comment: Your code works fine for me except that it throws an unrelated error after connecting. It is most certainly a problem with your server.

Comment: @Selcuk That's weird~ The web server code could run well when I use the browser to connect.

Comment: The meaning of the error is that nothing was listening at 127.0.0.1:8000. But the rest of your code makes no sense. You can't accept from a connected socket.

Answer (score -1):

In server instead of

```
serverSocket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8000))
```

do

```
serverSocket.bind(('<LAN/Local IP address>', 8000))
```

Example:

```
serverSocket.bind(('192.168.1.131', 8000))
```

And of course, you will use the same local IP address in client too.

Example:

```
python  ./client.py  192.168.1.131  8000  HelloWorld.html
```

Comment: As he is connecting to 127.0.0.1 there is no reason why binding to 127.0.0.1 would cause this error: and he is writing a client, not a server.

Answer (score -1):

socket probably got exhausted on your first pass (on your while loop). That was my problem when I got the same error. In my case my selenium webdriver object was getting consumed. You would have to reset your socket on each pass of the loop